# How Update / change part of string in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I must Update Oracle database with remove part of string, problem is that this part can be in multiple place in this string. Example:

I must remove part and Update database where clolumn_name like ('%,aaa%') from

'bbb,aaa,ccc,ddd' or 'bbb,ccc,aaa,ddd' or from 'bbb,ccc,eee,fff,aaa,ddd'

Please help me :)

Comment: [`REPLACE(ColumnName, ',aaa', '')`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REPLACE.html) helpful?

Comment: I must update database where column_name like ('%,aaa%,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace complete terms using simple string functions (which is much quicker than regular expressions) is:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(
         BOTH ',' FROM
         REPLACE(','||value||',', ',aaa,', ',')
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaa,bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ccc,aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ddd,aaa,eee' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'fff,aaa,ggg,aaa,hhh' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaa,aaa,aaa' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| REPLACED_VALUE |
| --- |
| *null* |
| bbb |
| ccc |
| ddd,eee |
| fff,ggg,hhh |
| aaa |

*Note: if you can have multiple sequential terms, as per the last example, then using simple string functions will not work; but in other cases when ther are non-sequential repeated terms it will work.*

---

If you can have multiple sequential repeated terms then you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT TRIM(
         BOTH ',' FROM
         REGEXP_REPLACE(','||value||',', '(,aaa)+,', ',')
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which outputs:

| REPLACED_VALUE |
| --- |
| *null* |
| bbb |
| ccc |
| ddd,eee |
| fff,ggg,hhh |
| *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PH3Slop5)

---

As for your comment:

> I must update database where `column_name like ('%,aaa%,)`

If you want to remove `aaa` from the start of each term (and remove empty terms) then:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET value = TRIM(
              BOTH ',' FROM 
              REGEXP_REPLACE(
                REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '(^|,)aaa', '\1'),
                ',{2,}',
                ','
              )
            )
WHERE value LIKE '%,aaa%'
OR    value LIKE 'aaa%'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MSKz0RAM)

Comment: @JonasMetzler The description says nothing about removing incomplete terms.

Comment: @SQL_Python_DataScience Updated with an `UPDATE` statement that removes `aaa` from the start of every term and also removes any empty terms.

Comment: I have check and I don't have any aaa on the start

this work perfect for my example :)

UPDATE table
SET column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '(^|,)aaa(.*?(,|$))', '\2')
WHERE column_name LIKE ('%,aaa%')

Thank you all for help :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use a regex replacement approach here:

```sql
SELECT val, TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(val, 'aaa,|,aaa,|,aaa', ',')) AS val_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

If you require an update, then use:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET val = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(val, 'aaa,|,aaa,|,aaa', ','))
WHERE ',' || val || ',' LIKE '%,aaa,%';
```

Comment: sorry I didn't add that I must to update the database and remove the 'aaa' signs where they occur

Comment: There are a few edge cases where this does not work [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TrreXiAl).